# Purpose of on/off circuit box next to circuit breaker in shared area

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have a circuit breaker in my apartment and one downstairs. However, the one downstairs has its own private on(black button, which lets the current through when pushed down and does not when tripped up), and off(red button, when pushed pops the black button up) buttons.

Could anyone please suggest the purpose of this second circuit breaker attached, and why once wound have had to attack this second circuit breaker?

[circuit breaker with circuit breaker to the left](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4TrFT2a3Od3aUJCanZEaEQ0YlU/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: I'm not sure of your area, but this setup is more typical of say a motor or such that would need to be started/stopped. What does that panel feed?

Comment: It sounds like the panel downstairs is the "master" panel for the whole apartment building, is that correct?  Also, where on the planet are you?